# Probability that X has a lower and upper bound

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose I have a random variable, X, (whose distribution is irrelevant) and I am interested in finding the probability that a $\leq$ X $\leq$ b.
Would this probability be equivalent to P(a$\leq$ X)*P(X $\leq$ b)?
That is, can I assume that these events are independent?

Comment: The events are clearly not independent.  Knowing that $X>b$, say, implies $X>a$.  And, to see that your formula is not correct, consider the case $a=b$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Counter example, consider $X$ is uniform.

Let $a=0.25$, $b=0.75$, $P(a \le X \le b)=0.5$

$P(a \le X)=\frac34=P(X\le b)$

$P(a \le X)P(X \le b)=\frac{9}{16}\ne \frac12$

Note that we have $P(a \le X \le b) = P(X \le b)-P(X < a) $ if that help in your computation.

Comment: Thank you so much!